# Flink slot removed exception

Tags: apache-flink

I am getting the following exception

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: The assigned slot container_1546939492951_0001_01_003659_0 was removed.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManager.removeSlot(SlotManager.java:789)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManager.removeSlots(SlotManager.java:759)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManager.internalUnregisterTaskManager(SlotManager.java:951)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManager.unregisterTaskManager(SlotManager.java:372)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.closeTaskManagerConnection(ResourceManager.java:823)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager.lambda$onContainersCompleted$0(YarnResourceManager.java:346)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:332)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:70)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.onReceive(AkkaRpcActor.java:142)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.onReceive(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:40)
at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

when running a batch process involving joining two very large datasets.

Here is what I can see in the overview. The failure happened on a task manager which did not get any inputs. Weirdly the previous set (partition -> flat map -> map) did not send anything to that task manager despite having a rebalance in front.

Am running it on EMR. I see that there is a *slot.idle.timeout*, would that have an effect and if so how do I specify it for that job? Can it be done on the command line?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

it's possible that this is a timeout issue, but usually when this happens to me it's because there's a failure (e.g. YARN kills the container because it's running beyond pmem or vmem limits). I'd recommend carefully checking the JobManager and all TaskManager log files.

Comment: it was running on EMR on top of YARN. I couldn't find a way to access the taskmanager logs after the job had finished unless the logging to S3 is activated. I've used a cluster with more disk space and have been able to complete the job since.

Comment: Hi Julien - nice that it was just a disk space issue. Just FYI, we usually keep the EMR cluster alive when debugging Flink jobs, because we sometimes have to poke around on the box to figure out what went wrong when a job fails. And yes, we also save logs to S3.

Comment: have you considered running it directly on EC2 with the standalone cluster? Apart from saving on the additional cost of EMR, would it be easier to find logs for the tasks?

Comment: We've done both approaches, but EMR in theory simplifies getting a properly configured YARN cluster set up and running.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line in java code.

`env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);`

then your job will start on cancellation automatically.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the ApiDoc? That would make it a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue which turned out to be excessive logging in our Flink job. I am guessing this resulted in Task Manager timeouts. Removing or reducing the amount of logging fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue when running Flink on Kubernetes, it turns out to be TaskManager was OOMKilled and restarted. If you also run Flink on Kubernetes, you can check the status of your TaskManager pods:

```
kubectl describe pods <pod>
```

if you see the container was previously OOKilled, that could be the cause:

```
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    137
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not always cause by oom and killed by yarn,if you have log like this:"Closing TaskExecutor connection container_e86_1590402668190_3503_01_000015 because: Container released on a *lost* node",and it is before your error log.I am guessing this problem cause by Nodemanager down.About 10 minutes ,flink ResourceManager can not communicate with NodeManager,ResourceManager will start to remove slot ,and restart(if you have restart strategy).